# Git conflicted copy error while cloning a repository

Tags: git, git-clone, merge-conflict-resolution

I am using dropbox as a git repository.

Now due to some issue in the syncing, there is some conflicted copy present in the git. How do  I remove this conflict ?
Due to this conflict I am unable to clone the contents of that repository.

The error I am getting while cloning the repository is:-

Git :- fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/heads/debugging (xyz conflictedcopy date) '

Comment: Using Dropbox as a git repository is a _really bad idea_.

Comment: Yeah I know that now. I will change it. But how do I remove the conflicts ? any pointers ?

Comment: What does `refs/heads/debugging` contain?

Comment: It contains files, which have records of the conflicted and normal copy. 
debugging
debugging (xyz's conflicted copy 2011-12-19)
master
master (xyzwer's conflicted copy 2011-09-24)
optimization
optimization (xyz's conflicted copy 2011-12-19)
production

Comment: Exact same problem.. today for the very first time after 4 years of git on dropbox.. are you using SourceTree by any chance? Haven't found a solution yet though.. there's nothing offensive under refs/heads/debugging..

Comment: @AkashDeshpande You'll have to pick which one you think is the most recent. The files in `refs/heads/` should be single files containing the latest commit hash for each branch.

Comment: No am not using source tree. But will stop using dropbox as repository.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin ok. After selecting should i delete the remaining files or copies?

Comment: @AkashDeshpande Back them up first! Just try to have it so that each branch has a single file in `refs/heads/` containing the hash of the last commit.

Comment: okay, no solution but an update. I have found out that this is a draconian check introduced in a recent git revision and there's some discussion about changing it to allow users to continue using the repository.. http://marc.info/?l=git&m=132009090127795&w=2

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Yes that works great :) I think .... I just removed the conflicted copies and its working great. Just add this as the answer. I will accept it.

Comment: A temporary solution is to revert back to an earlier git version. If like me you are on the Mac and on Lion, you should have version 1.7.5.4 installed in /Developer/usr/bin/git and that version works just fine. Might be a better solution that destroying your repository.

Comment: The discussion about what could be done also offers an indication that it's possible to update the references by doing something along the lines of: "    c=$(git rev-parse --force refs/patches/obd_development/blah:_vari...)
    git update-ref refs/patches/obd_development/blah--various-improvements $c". I don't know enough to start mucking around with it.. any help would be most welcome.

Comment: It did the same to me with my repo in a local google drive folder.

Comment: I'm dropping Dropbox.  It's mangled too many of my repos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution that eventually worked for me was to simply delete the branch that the reference refers to, e.g.

```
git branch -D "debugging (xyz conflictedcopy date)"
```

I had many such references, so it was "rinse and repeat"..

Answer (score 22):

```
Just delete every file in <Repo>/.git/ which ends in (... conflictedcopy <date>).
```

That will clean your git repo; the answer by Frank R. does in fact the same, while keeping the other by Dropbox abused files :)

Answer (score 12):

A quick way to apply the solutions from kenansulayman and Frank R. is with the following command, that should be ran from the root of the defective repository:

```
find .git -name '*conflicted*' -exec rm {} \;
```

Notice: I assume you don't have any branches, tags (or some other git object) with the string `conflicted` in their names. If you do, that command will also delete those wanted files.

That worked for me. Cheers.

Comment: For your answer references our answers, you could have added this as a comment

Comment: My idea was to help visitors the most. As a comment, this tip wouldn't get the same visibility and its formatting would be precarious.