# Dropbox overwrote .git with older version

Tags: git

I recently ran into a problem with Dropbox where it would repeatedly sync the same files. I reset it and let is sync all my files again. Unfortunately I think it overwrote my local `.git` file with a older version that it pulled from the cloud.

When I run `git status` I get a list of like a hundred "conflicted" files. When I run `git diff` it's empty. I'm not sure how to proceed without screwing up my branch. I tried `git pull staging master` (my staging master is up to date) when on my `working` branch, but I got an error telling me to either commit or delete untracked files.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227820/git-conflicted-copy-error-while-cloning-a-repository) post on the issue but the answers didn't help me out.

When I inspect the files, the conflicted files are the current versions, while the other versions are outdated. Would deleting all the conflicted files and then running `git pull staging master` solve the problem?

Comment: That's why you should **never** sync git repositories using Dropbox, Google Drive, etc. If you don't have any local changes, you can just remove folder and clone it again from remote.

Comment: Yeah, definitely learned my lesson there. I ended up just deleting all the files and pulling the master from staging. Lost my last commit from local, but I can live with that.